# In ActionScript3, how do you get a reference to an object's class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In ActionScript3, how do you get a reference to an object's class?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203969/how-do-i-get-from-an-instance-of-a-class-to-a-class-object-in-actionscript-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `constructor` property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Object.html#constructor) if your object has been created from a class (from the docs: *"If an object is an instance of a class, the constructor property holds a reference to the class object. If an object is created with a constructor function, the constructor property holds a reference to the constructor function."*):

```
var classRef:Class = myObject.constructor as Class;
```

Or you can use [`flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()) and [`flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) (not a very nice way since this entails unnecessary string manipulation in the implementations of these library functions):

```
var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(myObject)) as Class;
```

Answer (score 10):

It's worth noting that the XML objects (XML, XMLList) are an exception to this (ie. (new XML() as Object).constructor as Class == null). I recommend falling back to getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName) when constructor does not resolve:

```
function getClass(obj : Object) : Class
{
    var cls : Class = (obj as Class) || (obj.constructor as Class);

    if (cls == null)
    {
        cls = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(obj));
    }

    return cls;
}
```

Note that getDefinitionByName will throw an error if the class is defined in a different (including a child) application domain from the calling code.